# What does "little that, lesser" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Orson Welles: Gotta run. I'm doing tests for [Heart of Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Darkness#Adaptations_and_influences).
>
> Mank: Oh, **little that, lesser** [Joe Conrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Conrad).

What does "little that, lesser" mean?

It's from *Mank (2020)*.

Comment: Just want to point out that this is a wierd expression. If anything it's archaic .. I have never heard it and didn't understand it either as a native speaker

Comment: It's a very bad pun using: A little of this and a little of that. OR a variation: I want a little of this and **less of that**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark is probably saying that *Heart of Darkness* is just a "little thing", one of Joseph Conrad's lesser (that is, less important) works.

I'm not sure critics would agree. That may be part of the context.

Comment: Yes, but he even calls him Joe instead of Joseph.

Comment: @ColleenV My typo - small font in my browser. Fixed.

Comment: The question still says Mank, not Mark :) I empathize about the font though ... there was a question a while back about  “pom” and a lot of people read it as “porn”. This font is not very easy to read .

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t a ‘set phrase’ in English, so the meaning will be shaped by the greater context (section, chapter, book) and background (e.g. popular culture at the time the book was written).

One strong possibility is that Mank was making something like an if-then statement:

- If (or “Since”) there is little of that, there will be less of what Joe Conrad is famous for (e.g. writing novels).

Even this structure can be interpreted multiple ways, one of which is:

- If Orson Welles does only a few “tests” (understood in the sense of reading portions of his book on radio or in preparation for a recording), he will have less chance of his novel becoming popular.

You will need to analyse the broader context to work out the meaning of heavily ellipsed (some words dropped) statements such as Mank’s.